# Restricted API gives no response

Tags: android, google-play

I have a challenge I need your help with. If I restrict my API Key Application restrictions to "Android" (for which my project is based), it stops giving JSON response, but gives the error. But when I set restrictions to "none", it gives good JSON response. And Google Play console won't let me upload my app if I don't restrict my API (which I understand is for my good, to help safeguard my API). How do I fix this please?

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Requests from this Android client application \u003cempty\u003e are blocked.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Requests from this Android client application \u003cempty\u003e are blocked.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

Comment: What `restriction` and what `response` are you talking about?

Comment: Please remember when posting here that we have zero information about what you're asking, so you need to fully explain. We can't read your mind from here to know what you're thinking; we only have the information you've made available to us in your question.